# Using variables in mysql update query

Tags: php, mysql, xhtml

This is what i'm trying to do, I have a form in one page:

```
<form action="update.php" method="post" value="">
<textarea name="update">
<?php $page_name = "home"; $tablename = "pages"; $columnname = "content"; $redirect="formulier_home.php"; ?>
<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT $columnname FROM $tablename WHERE page_name = '$page_name'"); ?>
<?php include("../includes/content_in_textarea.php"); ?>
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Publiceer" >        
</form>
```

and I update in another page:

```
<?php require_once("../includes/connection.php"); ?>
<?php $opvangen = $_POST['update'];?>
<?php $content = nl2br($opvangen); ?>
<?php mysql_query("UPDATE $tablename SET $columnname='$content' WHERE page_name='$page_name'") or die (mysql_error());
header("Location:$redirect"); ?>
```

It works fine if I don't use variables in the query like this:

```
<?php mysql_query("UPDATE $tablename SET $columnname='$content' WHERE page_name='$page_name'")or die (mysql_error());
header("Location:$redirect"); ?>
```

But I'm a little confused on how I will transfer the variables to the update page, I want to 
use the update page for all my columns and pages that I want to adjust.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your goal/problem is.

Answer (score 1):

If you want push variables from one site to other you need to use $_SESSION as @SomeKittens wrote or use a hidden form field. $_SESSION is better becouse the user can't overwrite it.

Put this in your form container file's first line:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

The form:

```
<form action="update.php" method="post">
<textarea name="update">
<?php
  $_SESSION['page_name'] = "home";
  $_SESSION['tablename'] = "pages";
  $_SESSION['columnname'] = "content";
  $_SESSION['redirect'] ="formulier_home.php";
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT {$_SESSION['columnname']} FROM {$_SESSION['tablename']} WHERE page_name = '{$_SESSION['$page_name']}'");
  include("../includes/content_in_textarea.php");
?>
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Publiceer" >        
</form>
```

Your upload.php:

```
<?php
session_start(); // You need to put this in first line all the time when you use the $_SESSION global variable!
require_once("../includes/connection.php");
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
 $opvangen = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['update']);
 $content = nl2br($opvangen);
 $result = mysql_query("UPDATE {$_SESSION['tablename']} SET {$_SESSION['columnname']}='$content' WHERE page_name='{$_SESSION['page_name']}'") or die (mysql_error());
 header("Location:{$_SESSION['redirect']}");
}
?>
```

And that's all what you need.

Comment: Hey thanks you guys, I'm sorry but I prob did something stupid so half over my story was not in the post. the whole idea i had was having one page to update all the forms i have on my website, but the problem was I could not find a way to push the variable values from a for

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "transfer" variables from one page to another, you should use the [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) superglobal.

As a side note, [**please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: I couldn't understand the question very well, but there's also query strings: `header('Location: /some/place?var1='.$value);` etc..